How to query JPA LocalDate field by passing a month and year as arguments?
I have the following entity with a LocalDate transactionDate field:
public class Revenue {

... (Other fields omitted for simplicity)

  @Column(name = "transaction_date")
  private LocalDate transactionDate;

I want to retrieve all revenues for a specific month of a year. The URI should be something like: /revenue/{year}/{month}.
Is it possible to do this with JPA Query Methods out-of-the-box?
I've tried the following:
@Repository
public interface RevenueRepository extends JpaRepository<Revenue, Long> {

  @Query(
      "SELECT r FROM revenue WHERE YEAR(r.transactionDate) = :year AND MONTH(r.transactionDate) = :month")
  Page<Revenue> findByYearAndMonth(
      @Param("year") int year, @Param("month") int month, Pageable pageable);


...

public interface RevenueService {

  Page<RevenueDTOResponse> getByYearAndMonth(int year, int month, Pageable pageable);

...

@Service
public class RevenueServiceImpl implements RevenueService {

  @Autowired private RevenueRepository revenueRepository;

  @Override
  public Page<RevenueDTOResponse> getByYearAndMonth(int year, int month, Pageable pageable) {
    return revenueRepository.findByYearAndMonth(year, month, pageable).map(RevenueDTOResponse::new);
  }

...

  @GetMapping("/{year}/{month}")
  public ResponseEntity<Page<RevenueDTOResponse>> getByYearAndMonth(
      @PathVariable int year, int month, Pageable pageable) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(
        revenueService.getByYearAndMonth(year, month, pageable), HttpStatus.OK);
  }

But I encountered the following exception:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'revenueController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'revenueService': Error creating bean with name 'revenueServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'revenueRepository': Error creating bean with name 'revenueRepository' defined in budget.control.project.repository.RevenueRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page budget.control.project.repository.RevenueRepository.findByYearAndMonth(int,int,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page budget.control.project.repository.RevenueRepository.findByYearAndMonth(int,int,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:787) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at budget.control.project.ProjectApplication.main(ProjectApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'revenueServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'revenueRepository': Error creating bean with name 'revenueRepository' defined in budget.control.project.repository.RevenueRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page budget.control.project.repository.RevenueRepository.findByYearAndMonth(int,int,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page budget.control.project.repository.RevenueRepository.findByYearAndMonth(int,int,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:787) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'revenueRepository' defined in budget.control.project.repository.RevenueRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page budget.control.project.repository.RevenueRepository.findByYearAndMonth(int,int,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page budget.control.project.repository.RevenueRepository.findByYearAndMonth(int,int,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        ... 34 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page budget.control.project.repository.RevenueRepository.findByYearAndMonth(int,int,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page budget.control.project.repository.RevenueRepository.findByYearAndMonth(int,int,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:357) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:135) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        ... 44 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page budget.control.project.repository.RevenueRepository.findByYearAndMonth(int,int,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:100) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:70) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:60) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:170) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:252) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:111) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        ... 56 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'revenue'
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:848) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:753) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:136) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:364) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy123.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:94) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        ... 62 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'revenue'
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.resolveRootEntity(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2013) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitRootEntity(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1944) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitRootEntity(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$RootEntityContext.accept(HqlParser.java:2549) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitEntityWithJoins(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1914) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitFromClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1901) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuery(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1148) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:941) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$QuerySpecExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1869) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:926) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$SimpleQueryGroupContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1740) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSelectStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:402) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.buildSemanticModel(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:311) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.createHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.interpretHql(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:790) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:840) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        ... 69 common frames omitted


I think the problem is with your query. Try
@Query("SELECT r FROM Revenue r WHERE YEAR(r.transactionDate) = :year AND MONTH(r.transactionDate) = :month")
EDIT for clarification: From your code the entity name should be Revenue instead of revenue. Moreover, since you where using the "r" alias on the projection, you should declare it in the from. Differences are change to "Revenue r" where you had "revenue".

You are right, those are the changes. Edited the answer

Thank you, guys, it worked. Sorry about this. It's my first question here.
